Can't install python3-tflite-runtime
I am currently on a Raspberry Pi 5 with the 64-bit RPI OS and I've been trying to install python3-tflite-runtime by following this website : https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/reTerminal-DM-Yolo5/
However I keep getting this error  when executing sudo apt-get install python3-tflite-runtime:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-tflite-runtime : Depends: python3 (< 3.10) but 3.11.2-1+b1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I tried fixing broken packages with synaptic, using python 3.9.12 version or following other tutorials to install it but none worked I keep getting the same error.

There don't seem to be any package named python3-tflite-runtime. What I see however is tflite-runtime and it supports Python 3.8 - 3.11. See PyPi.
Also, the docs say:

Note: We no longer update the Debian package python3-tflite-runtime. The latest Debian package is for TF version 2.5, which you can install by following these older instructions.

See the docs.
